# From Matrix to polar plot

Tags: polar-coordinates, cylindrical

I have an np.array A in which a polar coordinate distribution Z=f(theta,r) is described by its elements Z=f(theta,r)=A[i,j]. I want to plot it in polar coordinates, like plt.imshow() does for Cartesian coordinates, if possible without converting it into Cartesian coordinates.

I've found [that](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/264048-how-to-draw-an-polar-image-under-polar-coordinate), which is the same subject, but on Matlab (I want to do it on Python).
I guess we should use [polar()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html), but the example presented doesn't correspond to what I want to do.

Thanks!